# Реализация кнопок для голосования

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Набросал код для кнопок для голосования. Режим работы должен быть таким:

1. При нажатии на кнопку увеличиваем счетчик голосов на единицу.
2. При повторном нажатии на эту же кнопку снимаем эту единицу.

Есть проблема с реализацией прибавления и вычитания. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

```js
function rate(type, id, r) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'function_rate.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'id': id,
            'type': type
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == 1) {
                if (type == 'p') {
                    document.getElementById('r1').innerHTML = ++r;
                } else if (type == 'm') {
                    document.getElementById('r2').innerHTML = ++r;
                }
            } else if (data == 2) {
                if (type == 'p') {
                    document.getElementById('r1').innerHTML = --r;
                } else if (type == 'm') {
                    document.getElementById('r2').innerHTML = --r;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="r1">2</div>
<div id="r2">2</div>

Плюс: <a href="javascript:rate('p', '111','2');"></a>
Минус: <a href="javascript:rate('m', '111','2');"></a>
```

UPD:

Спасибо Regent! Хорошее решение, однако в нем плюсы и минусы вычисляются всегда от исходного значения, то есть если был рейтинг 6 при плюсе будет 7 при снятии этого плюса мы получим 6-1=5, а необходимо уже 7-1. Но при этом и возврат от исходного тоже должен работать, при случае, если пользователь обновил страницу.

И этот пример не работает с разными значениями рейтинга в плюсе и в минусе.

Попытался поправить ниже, но что-то делаю не так по незнанию.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.rate').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $this.data('id');
        var type = $this.data('type');
        $.ajax({
            url: '', //для тестов
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 'id': id, 'type': type },
            success: onSuccess
        });
        function onSuccess(data) {
            data = $this.data('test'); //для тестов

            var $element;
            var baseValue;
            
            if (type == 'p') {
                $element = $('#r1');
                $baseValue = parseInt($('#r1').text());
            }
            else {
                $element = $('#r2');
                $baseValue = parseInt($('#r2').text());
            }
            var change = -1;
            if ((type == 'p' && data == 1) || (type == 'm' && data == 2)) {
                change = 1;
            }
            $element.text(baseValue + change);          
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Равно ли значение 1 или 2 решает php скрипт. То есть он определяет голосовал ли пользователь уже отрицательно или положительно, если да то выводит 2. Если голосует впервые то 1. Скрипт получает `$_POST['type']` равный "m" или "p" при минусе и плюсе.

Comment: Каждой кнопке будет соответствовать значение рейтинга. Визуально это будет оформлено красиво и понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Изначальная версия**

Заменил `javascript:` внутри `href` на `$('.rate').on('click', function() { ... });`, предварительно добавив ссылкам `<a>` класс `rate` и атрибуты `data-type` и `data-id`.

Логику изменения значений `r1` и `r2` реализовал ровно так, как я её понял.

Дополнительные две ссылки и атрибут `data-test` добавлены для тестирования различных (`1` и `2`) значений возвращаемой `data`.

HTML:

```
<div id="r1">2</div>
<div id="r2">2</div>

<a href="" class="rate" data-type="p" data-id="111" data-test="1">Плюс(data=1)</a>
<a href="" class="rate" data-type="m" data-id="111" data-test="1">Минус(data=1)</a>
<br/>
<a href="" class="rate" data-type="p" data-id="111" data-test="2">Плюс(data=2)</a>
<a href="" class="rate" data-type="m" data-id="111" data-test="2">Минус(data=2)</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var baseValue = parseInt($('#r1').text());

    $('.rate').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $this.data('id');
        var type = $this.data('type');
        $.ajax({
            url: '', //для тестов
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 'id': id, 'type': type },
            success: onSuccess
        });
        function onSuccess(data) {
            data = $this.data('test'); //для тестов
            var $element;
            if (type == 'p') {
                $element = $('#r1');
            }
            else {
                $element = $('#r2');
            }
            var change = -1;
            if ((type == 'p' && data == 1) || (type == 'm' && data == 2)) {
                change = 1;
            }
            $element.text(baseValue + change);          
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

[Полный пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tm4hx7q1/).

**Итоговая версия**, полученная общими усилиями:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var baseValue = parseInt($('#r1').text());
    var baseValue2 = parseInt($('#r2').text());

    $('.rate').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $this.data('id');
        var type = $this.data('type');
        $.ajax({
            url: '',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'id': id,
                'type': type
            },
            success: onSuccess
        });

        function onSuccess(data) {
            var $element;
            if (type == 'p') {
                $element = $('#r1');
                var value = baseValue;
            } else if (type == 'm') {
                $element = $('#r2');
                var value = baseValue2;
            }

            if (data == 1) {
                change = 1;
            } else if (data == 2) {
                change = -1;
            }

            if ($element.hasClass('voted')) {
                value = parseInt($element.text());
            }
            if (data > 0) {
                $element.text(value + change).toggleClass('voted');
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, вынес продолжение в основной вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, подправил немного.  [Получилось](http://jsfiddle.net/m84w3qzg/3/) то, что нужно.

Comment: Добавил откорректированный, последний, вариант UPD2 в основной вопрос.

Comment: @Ivan_Aka это неправильный подход. Вопрос не должен содержать ответ. Вариантов решения ситуации 3: 1. Вы можете просто удалить вопрос. 2. Я могу разместить итоговый код в своём ответе, а вы его отметите как правильный. 3. Вы можете разместить свой код в своём ответе и отметить его как правильный, а я свой ответ удалю.

Comment: Однозначно вариант 2

Comment: @Ivan_Aka код добавил в ответ. Из Ajax-запроса убрал `async: false`, потому что это, грубо говоря, "чистое зло" - религия мне не позволяет добавить эту строку в код. Сам код, в целом, выглядит хорошо (тестировать - не тестировал). _UPD2_ убрал из вопроса.

Comment: Но без этого async: false при очень быстрых кликах по кнопкам получается сбой. Если, например, кликать по кнопке Плюса и рейтинг будет меняться с 0 на 1 и обратно, то в определенный момент времени он может перескочить на -1.

Comment: @Ivan_Aka в таком случае лучше использовать флаг, который будет запрещать повторный Ajax-запрос до завершения первого.

Comment: Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: @Ivan_Aka вот [схематичный пример](http://jsfiddle.net/6zqpbw40/) использования флага в такой ситуации.

Comment: Это я так понимаю просто ставим таймаут. Честно говоря не понимаю почему в данной ситуации async: false является злом. Он же не влияет на загрузку страницы. Включается в работу после клика по кнопке...

Comment: @Ivan_Aka проблема в том, что при `async: false` браузер вообще ни на что (клики, скролл и прочее) не отзывается во время запроса к серверу. Если запрос идёт 1-2 секунды, то это почти незаметно. Но стоит из-за проблем сети или сервера ему "застрять" секунд на 10+  - пользователи начнут страдать.